# PhD application form, 1-2 word "relationship to you" for an instructor

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm working on my PhD applications right now, and I'm on the section where I have to fill in information about recommendation providers.
I have put a Professor that taught one of my related course as a recommendation provider, however I'm not sure what I should put under "relationship to you". Any suggestion? (there's not a lot of space, I can only put in one or two words)

Comment: "I was a student in class XXX taught by him"

Comment: I can only put in one or two words in the blank

Comment: Course Instructor

Answer (score 6):

As you've stated that you have only space for 1-2 words, this necessitates the description to be brief and to the point.

Suggestions are:

'Course Instructor' - or if possible, replace the word 'Course' with the actual course.

or just use 'Professor' (or whatever their rank is).